# Import multiple custom modules at once

Tags: python

I have a custom python module named `views.py`.

Inside this module, there are functions:

```
view1()
view2()
view3()
```

These functions are pretty big, and I want to split their implementation into multiple files : `view1.py,  view2.py,  view3.py`

While being still able to load them at once with something like:

```
import mylib.views as vs

vs.view1()
vs.view2()
vs.view3()
```

Comment: Create the same function and then call the main function inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mylib.views` can simply be a wrapper module that imports `view1`, `view2`, and `view3` from their respective files.  For example:

```
from .view1 import view1
from .view2 import view2
from .view3 import view3
```

You can `import` the `import`s of other modules, so using this wrapper would look just like your second example.

```
import mylib.views as vs

vs.view1()
vs.view2()
vs.view3()
```

Comment: Thanks !! So easy I didn't think of it 